# How can I set up Gmail to change the from/to address when automatically forwarding email?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, email-forwarding

I have two Gmail accounts: my normal Gmail account (`me@gmail.com`), and an account for my school that is hosted through Gmail (`me@school.edu`).

I get lots of emails on both accounts, and some people send me emails in multiple contexts (friends that I work with). I have all emails from `me@school.edu` automatically forward to `me@gmail.com`, so that I have a single point of searching and archiving and don't always have to swap back and forth between accounts to do some basic things. In `me@gmail.com`, I *try* to filter all of these forwarded emails in my `School` label and then archive them from my inbox.

This runs into a problem when the email that goes to `me@school.edu` does not include my direct email, like for mailing lists or some forms of bcc. Gmail forwards the email with the original from (`sender@school.edu`) and to (`list@school.edu` or `otherlist@groups.aol.com`), and so it ends up unread in my `me@gmail.com` inbox.

How can I change either the `to:` address on the forwards to `me@gmail.com` OR the `from:` address to `me@school.edu`, so that I can set up a filter that works in all situations?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want the `deliveredto:` search operator.

[Gmail advanced search](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190)

> **deliveredto:**
>
> Search for messages within a particular email address in the Delivered-To line of the message header   Example: `deliveredto:username@gmail.com`
>
> Meaning: Any message with `username@gmail.com` in the Delivered-To: field of the message header (which can help you find messages forwarded from another account or ones sent to an alias).

You should be able to replace your `to:me@school.edu` filter with `has the words: deliveredto:me@school.edu`. That should catch mailing lists and such.